# Expected value for f(x)

Tags: references, expected-value, moments, multivariate-normal-distribution

I am reading an article and trying to extend their case to a multivariate case.
I have the function

$f_{i} (x)=\frac{1}{|Σ|}f_{0}((x-μ_{i})'Σ^{-1}(x-μ_{i}))$, where $f_{0}(.)$   is a base density function.

I am trying to find $∫xf_i^2 (x)dx$

But the article does not provide any instructions or details about how they found their results.

Is there a good source that provide how a way of finding this expected value?

Comment: Since you say nothing about $f_0,$ there's little one can say.  Could you tell us what $f_0$ is?

Comment: The article does not mention anything about $f_{0} (.)$ but the fact that it is a base density function.

Comment: Then in what sense do you mean to "find" this integral?

Comment: Can I write it in terms of integral or simplify it? and solve it for $\mu$?

Comment: When $f_i$ is unspecified, there's no simplification.

Comment: The article that I am reading uses the univariate case. It assumes that the following holds $f_{i}=\frac{1}{\sigma} f_{0}(\frac{x-\mu_{i}}{\sigma})$. Then, they concluded that   $∫xf^2_{i}(x)dx =∫(\frac{y\sigma+\mu_{i}}{\sigma})f^2_{0}(y)dy $ but I can understand what they did exactly.

Comment: That move was made *via* the substitution $\sigma x + \mu_i=y.$  It a technique of integration, so if it's unfamiliar, you can find an account of it in any differential Calculus textbook.

Comment: Thank you very much! That helps a lot